# SQL Server XML query using xquery with repeating relational data

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a questionnaire stored in a XML column that I want to store in a non-xml table format instead. The source table looks like this:

```
ID          VERSION content
----------- ------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
1211        96      <QS mg_id="1" locale_id="0" logoimg="inbox/FormImages/15/180.gif"...
1211        97      <QS mg_id="1" locale_id="0" logoimg="inbox/FormImages/15/180.gif"...
```

content:

```
<QS mg_id="1" locale_id="0" logoimg="inbox/FormImages/15/180.gif">
  <PAGE id="1" topic="Demographics" progress="9" background="inbox/FormImages/15/176.gif" lastPage="false" flush_concepts="1">
    <QUESTION id="2" type="dropdown" style="font-family:arial;font-size:12px;color:#086BB5;font-weight:bold;" value="What is your age?" defaultvalue="" listid="" conceptid="">
      <OPTIONS>
        <OPTION score="0" concept_value="1" value="I am under 18" url="" id="0" />
        <OPTION score="0" concept_value="2" value="Between 18 and 30 years old" url="" id="1" />
        <OPTION score="0" concept_value="3" value="Between 30 and 50 years old" url="" id="2" />
        <OPTION score="0" concept_value="4" value="Between 50 and 70 years old" url="" id="3" />
        <OPTION score="0" concept_value="5" value="Between 70 and 90 years old" url="" id="4" />
        <OPTION score="0" concept_value="6" value="Over 90 years old" url="" id="5" />
      </OPTIONS>
    </QUESTION>
    <QUESTION id="4" type="dropdown" style="font-family:arial;font-size:12px;color:#086BB5;font-weight:bold;" value="Do you have children?" defaultvalue="" listid="" tooltip="" usability="5">
      <OPTIONS>
        <OPTION score="0" concept_value="1" value="Yes" url="" id="0" />
        <OPTION score="0" concept_value="0" value="No" url="" id="1" />
      </OPTIONS>
    </QUESTION>
</PAGE>
</QS>
```

And I want to get output of the form:

```
ID          VERSION QuestionID QuestionValue     OptionID  OptionValue
----------- ------- ---------- ----------------- --------- -------------------------------
1211        96        2        What is your age?        1   I am under 18
1211        96        2        What is your age?        2   Between 18 and 30 years old
....
1211        96        4        Do you have children     1   Yes
....
1211        97        2 ...
```

Is there a way to do that using a select statement with SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    ID, 
    Version,
    Q.value('(@id)[1]', 'int') AS 'QuestionID',
    Q.value('(@value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'QuestionValue',
    OPT.value('(@id)[1]', 'int') AS 'OptionID',
    OPT.value('(@value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'OptionValue'
FROM
    dbo.YourTableNameHere
CROSS APPLY 
    XmlCol.nodes('QS/PAGE/QUESTION') AS QS(Q)
CROSS APPLY
    QS.Q.nodes('./OPTIONS/OPTION') AS OPTS(OPT)
```

You need to use two `CROSS APPLY` operators to

- get a list of all `<QUESTION>` nodes inside your XML
- get a sub-list of all `<OPTION>` nodes inside a given `<QUESTION>` to get the option information for each question

Comment: Very cool. Does SQL Server 2008 R1 have the ".nodes" method? It doesn't seem to recognize it.

Comment: @pru: yes, that's part of XQuery which was introduced in SQL Server 2005 and newer. You need to be careful when typing - those method names are **case-sensitive!** (it has to be `.nodes()` in all **lowercase**)

Comment: I should be able to eventually figure it out but content is Varchar(max) although it contains xml and SELECT 
   [ID]
      ,[VERSION]
     from QSA
  cross apply 
  Convert(XML,content).nodes('QS/PAGE/QUESTION') AS QS(Q)   gives me the error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Convert'.

Comment: @pru: either change your datatype to `XML` (preferred), or use `CAST(content AS XML).nodes(....)` as an intermediate solution - hope that works

Comment: That won't work either: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. As far as changing to XML, I can't do that since it is a external system written by another company with read-only access.

Comment: with fix_qsa (id, version, md) as (select ID,version,CONVERT(xml,meta_data) md from QSA)
SELECT
    ID, 
    Version,
    Q.value('(@id)[1]', 'int') AS 'QuestionID',
    Q.value('(@value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'QuestionValue',
    OPT.value('(@id)[1]', 'int') AS 'OptionID',
    OPT.value('(@value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'OptionValue'
FROM
    fix_qsa
CROSS APPLY 
    md.nodes('QS/PAGE/QUESTION') AS QS(Q)
CROSS APPLY
    QS.Q.nodes('./OPTIONS/OPTION') AS OPTS(OPT)

Comment: That executes, but returns 0 rows :-(

Comment: Found the problem. I had a typo in the Xpath expression. It all works now. Thanks a ton marc!

Comment: I have a dropdownlist for which I would like to update the index based on what is provided by the user. Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398808/how-to-update-dropdownlist-xml-node-in-cms-through-sql Can you please help.